# OSX 10.9.5, Gnuplot 4.6.6 and XQuartz 2.7.7 don't work together

Tags: macos, gnuplot, homebrew, x11

I'm trying to use gnuplot at OSX with X11 terminal. I downloaded the newest version of XQuartz 2.7.7 and I brewed gnuplot 4.6.6 --with-x option. However, when I try

> gnuplot> plot(sin(x))

XQuartz opens, but there is no window with the plot. When I do "Show All Windows", there is nothing at all. I can gnuplot into png. I can also open "xterm" through the terminal. I tried to reinstall both programs many times, but nothing seems to work.

Any idea where could be a problem? (I need these two tools because of Octave.)
Thank you

Comment: Just a thought... I know nothing about XQuartz, but have you set DISPLAY environment variable appropriately and do you need to do `xhost +` with Quartz?

Comment: I gave up and used AquaTerm instead. I had to manually install AquaTerm from http://sourceforge.net/projects/aquaterm/ and then rebrew gnuplot --with-aquaterm. This solution is good enough.